# Differentiation of dot product of vector valued functions.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry

Let $a:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^n$ and $b:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^n$ be differentiable vector-valued functions.

${\frac d {d x} } {\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b} = \dfrac {d \mathbf a} {d x} \cdot \mathbf b + \mathbf a \cdot \dfrac {d \mathbf b} {d x}$
($\cdot$ is dot product). Here is the proof:

> \begin{align*}
> \frac{d\bf v}{dx}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{{\bf v}(x+h)-{\bf v}(x)}{h}\\
> &=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{{\bf a}(x+h)\cdot{\bf b}(x+h)-{\bf a}(x)\cdot{\bf b}(x)}{h}\\
> &=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{{\bf a}(x+h)\cdot{\bf b}(x+h)-{\bf a}(x+h)\cdot{\bf b}(x)+{\bf a}(x+h)\cdot{\bf b}(x)-{\bf a}(x)\cdot{\bf b}(x)}{h}\\
> &=\lim_{h\to 0}{\bf a}(x+h)\cdot\frac{{\bf b}(x+h)-{\bf b}(x)}{h}+\lim_{h\to0}\frac{{\bf a}(x+h)-{\bf a}(x)}{h}\cdot{\bf b}(x)\\
> &={\bf a}\cdot\frac{d\bf b}{dx}+\frac{d\bf a}{dx}\cdot{\bf b}
> \end{align*}

Part that I can't understand is from what follows that you can write $\lim$ as sum of $\lim$-its.

I know that if $r_1(x),r_2(x)$ are real valued vector functions then limit of sum is equal to sum of limits.And if we have $f(M)$ and vector function $r_1(M)$ then limit of multiplication of those is just multiplication of limits.

But in these problem question arises because $h \to 0$ then shouldn't by above assumption when we write sum of limits there already be $0$ instead of $h$?

EDIT.
Question is here.
$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a(x+h)\cdot b(x+h)}{h}+\frac{c(x+h)\cdot d(x+h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a(x+h)\cdot b(x+h)}{h}+\lim_{h\to0}\frac{c(x+h)\cdot d(x+h)}{h}$

Comment: If I understand correctly, your misanderstanding is the following: $\lim \mathbf{a}(t) \cdot \mathbf{b}(t) = (\lim \mathbf{a}(t)) \cdot (\lim \mathbf{b}(t)$. This can be easily proven if you expand what the dot product means in terms of sums of products of the components!

Comment: @topolosaurus I edited I think it's clear now